# How to refresh filtered aurelia repeat.for binding

Tags: aurelia

Given a class with a  list of items that is bound to multiple lists in the view, what is the recommended way to refresh the view when an element is modified?

Do I remove the old item and add the new item, raise an event, or something else?

```
export class Model {
  items: Item[];
  filter1 = x => x.isActive;
  filter2 = x => x.Value > 5;

  modifyItem(item) {
    item.isActive = true;
    item.Value = 22;
  }
}


<template repeat.for="item of items | filter:filter1">...</template>
<template repeat.for="item of items | filter:filter2">...</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [signal binding behavior](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/5) to notify it that something has changed and the filter needs to be refreshed:

```
<template repeat.for="item of items | filter:filter1 & signal:'item-modified'">...</template>
```

And in your component:

```
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject()
export class Model {
  items: Item[];
  filter1 = x => x.isActive;
  filter2 = x => x.Value > 5;

  constructor(private signaler: BindingSignaler) { }

  modifyItem(item) {
    item.isActive = true;
    item.Value = 22;
    signaler.signal('item-modified');
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Documentation about the signaling is very bad on the aurelia docs.